# Why does quotient of basis for second order ODE solution must not equal to 0?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to understand the concept of Second Order ODE general solution, and I need help.
Why does a quotient of basis of a general solution $\neq constant$?

For example:
$y_1=e^x$ and $y_2=e^{-x}$ are solutions to ODE $y''-y=0$

Before stating general solution, it goes on to check that 
$$e^x/e^{-x}\neq constant$$
Why is that?
And what is this constant? Do they mean to say that "x" don't cancel as in $2x/2x=1$, and?

Here is the passage from the book that I'm referring to:
[image: General Solution to second order ODE]

Comment: Improvements or edits are welcome.

Comment: Why do you expect the quotient of some basis elements to be a constant?

Comment: Well, that's what I'm confused. That's what it says in the book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general solution of a homogeneous linear ODE of order $n$ consists of the linear combinations of a basis consisting of $n$ linearly independent solutions.  In the case $n=2$, for two solutions to be linearly independent is equivalent to neither being a constant multiple of the other, i.e. neither is identically $0$ anThe theory says what you need is a basis consisting of $n$ (in this case $2$) linearly independent solutions. d their quotient is not constant.

EDIT:  Sorry to sound like a book, but that's just the way I am.

This all comes from linear algebra, which it would be handy to know.

Let's stick to the case $n=2$.  Say you've found two solutions $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$.  It would be very bad if $f_2$ was a constant multiple of $f_1$, say $f_2(x) = c f_1(x)$, because then linear combinations of $f_1$ and $f_2$  doesn't give you any more solutions than you get with just $f_1$: $a f_1(x) + b f_2(x) = (a + b c) f_1(x)$.  So you check that 
$f_2(x)$ is not a constant multiple of $f_1(x)$ by seeing that $f_2(x)/f_1(x)$ is not constant.

In this example, with $f_1(x) = e^{-x}$ and $f_2(x) = e^x$, $f_2(x)/f_1(x) = e^x/e^{-x} = e^{2x}$, and that is not constant.  Or you could take $f_1(x)/f_2(x)$: again that isn't constant, so 
$f_1(x)$ is not a constant multiple of $f_2(x)$.

The theory tells you (and it's not hard to prove) that this is all you need to conclude that $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ are linearly independent and their linear combinations give you the general solution.

Comment: sorry mate, but you sound like my book, and I don't get you :(. Individual terms make sense, but I can't paint a big picture still.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful edit with the examples! This helped! =D

Comment: If I were to find the prove of the theory, that you mention in the last paragraph, where would I look for it?

Comment: For example, you might look [here](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~israel/m215/lin2o/lin2o.html).

Answer (score 3):

If the quotient of two solutions is constant that means that one is a constant multiple of another, which means that one is linearly dependent on the other, which means they cannot form a basis of solutions (a basis is a linearly independent and spanning set of solutions).

For instance, $e^x$ and $2e^x$ are both solutions to your ODE, but clearly they are linearly dependent since they have a quotient of $2$, so they can't form a basis.

Comment: So what would it mean when two solutions can't form a basis? can these solutions still be useful somehow?

Comment: The most general solution to a differential equation is given by an arbitrary linear combination of the solutions which form a basis. So here we have two linearly independent solutions ($e^x$ and $e^{-x}$) so the most general solution to your differential equation is given by $c_1 e^x + c_2 e^{-x}$. Your initial/boundary conditions determine the constants.

Comment: If two solutions can't form a basis then only one of them is really useful. For any given differential equation there are an infinity of solutions. The point of having a basis of solutions is so that you can characterise all the solutions given any initial or boundary conditions.

Comment: So you mean to say that I need to form basis of the solutions for the given ODE in order to simply describe it, right? and for 2nd order ODE, having only one solution does not fully describe the given ODE. Have I understood you correct?

Comment: That's the gist of it. The point of getting a basis is that you can use them to describe **any** solution to that ODE. It's also important to note that an ODE on its own does not have a particular unique solution, but if you give enough boundary/initial conditions and apply them you will get a particular unique solution... So, for example, $c_1 e^x + c_2 e^{-x}$ is the general solution to your ODE, but is not a particular unique solution since $c_1$ and $c_2$ are arbitrary. If you apply your initial conditions you will get $2e^x + 4e^{-x}$ which is a particular unique solution.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the purpose of forming basis. Until you did I didn't even realize, that I had no idea what it was used for :D

Comment: No problem, glad to be of use!